# BufferGeometry doesn't update even after needsupdate is set true

Tags: three.js

I'm struggling with updating point geometry in Three JS.
I tried to move individual points and eventually move to a point I want.
To keep things clean, I created a class constructor.

And it is rendered fine and rotates fine.
But only the point position is not updated.

I tried to update them like below.

```
function animate(target) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate.bind(target));
    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
        // elapsedTime; 
    frame += 0.01

sphereMesh.rotation.x = frame;

let { array, originalPosition } = sphereMesh.geometry.attributes.position;

for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    let i3 = i * 3;
    array[i3] = originalPosition[i3] * Math.sin(frame)
}
console.log(array[0])

sphereMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

The rotation is updated quite well while the positions are not updated.
It just moved to a direction at once and nothing happens after that.

The entire code running can be seen in the following link.

Demo: https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/project/editor/ZopwxV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> function animate(target) {

This line does not work. The argument of the animation callback functions is always a time value. Hence `target.length` is `undefined` and no geometry data are updated.

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO Much I tried to fix this for 20hours and didn't really think of the possibility at all you just rescued my weekend.

Comment: Please upvote the answer and mark it respectively.